# How does format specifier know how many bytes to print?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I have the following program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a='b';
    int b=11299;
    char d[4]="abc";
    printf("value of a is %d\n",a);
    printf("value of b is %c\n",b);
    printf("value of c is %d\n",*d);
    char *c=d;
    c=c+1;
    printf("c is %d\n",*c);
}
```

I am little confused with %d format specifier. I was thinking that it would print 4 bytes of data. But from the above program (first and last printf) it is evident that it prints only one byte when a char parameter is used. Why does %d print only one byte? How does it know how many bytes to print?

Comment: This is the [basic MSVC page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx) about `printf` format specifiers, and contains links to more detail, such as width. The plain `%d` specifier prints the given argument as `int` using as many digits as necessary.

Comment: When `a` is being passed to `printf()` it gets promoted to `int` by the compiler.

Comment: the `char` is promoted to `int`.

Comment: It neither prints 1 byte nor 4 bytes. According to `%d`, it expects and prints an `int` value. Similar for `%c` (well, `char` actually is a byte, so ...)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't print bytes; it prints values -- the value you pass as the corresponding argument -- provided the value passed has the right type.

In your example 1, the argument is the value `'b'`. It initially has type `char` (because the expression `a` has type `char`) but variadic arguments are subject to default promotions, which promote any integer type with lower rank than `int` up to `int`. Thus, as an argument, the type is `int`.

In your example 3, the argument is the value `'a'`. Likewise it initially has type `char` (because the expression `*d` has type `char`) but it gets promoted to `int`.

If promotions didn't happen and the types were wrong, though, `printf` still wouldn't "print fewer bytes". Your program would just have undefined behavior (so anything could happen). For example:

```
int a = 42;
printf("%lld\n", a); // undefined behavior because int does not
                     // get promoted implicitly to long long.
```

In your example 2, the `%c` format specifier expects an argument of type `int`; `printf` converts it to `unsigned char` and prints the corresponding character. Any value of `int` is acceptable; it doesn't have to already be a value in the range of `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're probably declaration specifying the ISO C90, and this forbids mixed declarations and code, as shown in the warning.
The statement pointer of type char c varible `char * c = d;` must be made for example of the statement string `d` `char d [4] = "abc";` and not in the middle of the code.
Second: `int main (){` function does not return anything, but this must specify to not pull warning.

The revised program would be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a='b';
    int b=11299;
    char d[4]="abc";
    char *c=d;
    printf("value of a is %d\n",a);
    printf("value of b is %c\n",b);
    printf("value of c is %d\n",*d);
    c=c+1;
    printf("c is %d\n",*c);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Err, how does this answer the question?